# Does upgrade ubuntu version 18.04 to 20.4 remove my /dev/sda3 data?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

I want to upgrade my ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.I have 2 partition drives '/' and '/dev/sda3'.In '/dev/sda3' drive have important files,i want to know that if upgrade to 20.04 does remove my '/dev/sda3' drive files?

By using this command:`sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3`

Comment: Always have a resent backup when doing upgrades .. in fact, just always have a recent backup, and know the procedure to restore it in full and partly. Please update your question with the output of ?  df -h`.

Comment: Any solution or tool to backup my drive data? Because i haven't USB which support 200GB data to store.

Comment: The upgrade should not touch your data, especially if it's not part of the system (like `/usr/bin`, `/etc`...), if you proceed carefully (choose the right upgrade option, "keep data...", avoid "erase disk"!). But, just in case, copy the data somewhere beforehand.